# Omnetpp Debugger: fatal error: 'library/library.h' file not found

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, omnet++, seal

I want to debug a omnetpp program and the program uses external library seal. The program is able to access seal library in normal `run` mode but in `debugger` mode. It is unable to access the external library.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it'll solve you're problem, but... When I've had a problem like this (code runs normally, but doesn't work when debugging), the problem is usually solved by installing the development version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly signifies that a compiler can't find a header, so your `#include` directive is failing. Without any details I assume that you haven't added a path to a header to your debug configuration. Check `Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols` and there you should add a path to the headers of your library (right side `Add`) under `Languages->GNU C/GNU C++` (left side) for a `Configuration->debug` (upper side)